# how to call method which is defined in a file another file in react native

Tags: react-native, pagination, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to implement pagination in a flat list, I had defined a custom hook to fetch the data from API using the fetch method. I had defined loadMoreItem method in a custom hook file, but I want to call that loadMoreItem in another separate flat list file. how to do that I tried to import the file but it is not working.

useFetchData.js

```
  import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
  import { Alert } from 'react-native';
  //import all the components we are going to use.
  import axios from 'axios';





 const useFetchData = (url) => {

//custom hook to fetch api
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [pageNo, setPageNo] = useState(1);



//fetch method
const getDataUsingFetch = async () => {
    try {
        await fetch(url)
            .then((res) => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw Error('could not fetch data for the resource')
                }
                return res.json()
            })

            .then((json) => setData(json));
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert(error);
    }
}
//loading more contacts data 
const loadMoreItem = () => {
    setPageNo(pageNo + 1);
};

//get contact data fetch method
const getContactsData = async () => {
    try {
        await fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api/?page=${pageNo}&results=10`)
            .then((res) => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw Error('could not fetch data for the resource')
                }
                return res.json()
            })

            .then((data) => setData([...data, ...json?.results]));
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert(error);
    }
}

//axios methodz
const getDataUsingAxios = () => {
    axios
        .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
        .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            alert(response.data.title);

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            alert(error.message);
        })

};




useEffect(() => {

    getDataUsingFetch();
    // getDataUsingAxios()

}, [url]);

return [data];
};

  export default useFetchData;
```

dataList.js

```
  import { StyleSheet, Text,FlatList } from 'react-native'
  import React from 'react'

  const dataList = ({data}) => {
  return (
  <FlatList
    data={data}
    keyExtractor={data.id}
    onEndReached={loadMoreItem} // error
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <Text>Task:{item.title} | Update: 
  {JSON.stringify(item.completed)} </Text>
    )}
  />
 )
}

export default dataList
```

Comment: share full code

Comment: If you would like to call a function in another file. First you need to import file by `import fetchDataHook from '../../hooks/useFetchData'`. Then your function calling should be `fetchDataHook.loadMoreItem()`. Btw, you are suggested that sharing your full code in text instead of images.

Comment: @PeterTam I tried this approach but it is not working

Comment: You cannot call your function since your function is inside `const getDataUsingFetch` and you export as default instead of stand alone function `{fetchDataHook}`. I would suggest you to combine 2 files in this case.